# Android Manifest's android:exported="true" to work the deep link

Tags: android, security, deep-linking

Good day!

I have an activity that has android:exported="true" and it is use to work the deep linking. Then the security team tag that as security issue. Is there a way to implement the deep linking more secured?

Answer (score 0):

To create a deep link, you can try creating a whitelist with intent filters only for those coming from the URL you specify.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/path" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this response, the deep link function is already implemented the only issue is because the activity has an attribute of android:exported="true". The security team tag that as vulnerability issue.

Comment: If you added a whitelist, it will not work outside the whitelist. In this case, why does it create a security vulnerability? If the security team can trigger activity from outside while the whitelist is added, they must communicate exactly what the problem is.